# Python Tkinter: ¿Puedo... en vez de importar y ejecutar una funcion... ejecutar todo el script desde otro script?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa con muchos programas a la vez, y en el menu hay botones que ejecutan diferentes aplicaciones

Entonces, primero hay un boton para ejecutar la calculadora, como la caluladora no necesita imagenes ni acceder a un archivo JSON, se ejecuta sin problemas pero todo el codigo lo tengo guardado en una funcion llamada main

Luego, hay un boton que deberia ejecutar un reproductor de musica, PERO ese SI NECESITA IMAGENES, entonces no funciona, me aparece un error

Codigo del MENU:

```
import repcarpeta.repmain # Aca importo: En la carpeta "repcarpeta" el archivo "repmain.py"

# Y aca se necesita ejecutar en una funcion:
def openRep():
    repcarpeta.repmain.main() # Esto no funciona, el programa no se ejecuta porque necesita acceder a una carpeta externa con las imagenes necesarias
```

Entonces... ¿Como hago para ejecutar todo un script? ¿O hay una solucion a esto?

Saludos!

EDIT: Agrego la carpeta y los subdirectorios que hay en mi programa:

Principalmente, el programa accede a 2 carpetas, una llamada "assets", donde se encuentran todas las imagenes necesarias; Y la ootra seria su propia carpeta, donde accede a un archivo JSON

```
repcarpeta:
           repdata.json
           repmain.py
assets:
       Aqui hay solo imagenes, en formatos JPG y PNG
```

Salida: tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage5" doesn't exist

Codigo entero:

```
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pytube;
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from pygame import mixer
import pyperclip;
import webbrowser;

mixer.init()

isplaying = False

def importSong():
    songs = fd.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Elije cancion(es)!", filetypes=(("MP3 Files (.mp3)", "*.mp3"), ("OGG Files (.ogg)", "*.ogg"), ("WAW Files (.waw)", "*.waw"), ("Todos los archivos", "*.*")))
    for song in songs:
        song = song.replace("C:/Users/User/Downloads/", "")
        song = song.replace(".mp3", "")
        
        queue.insert(END, song)

i = 0

def play():
    global i
    global openMusic, isplaying, o, volumen
    if (isplaying):
        mixer.music.pause()
        i = 1
        isplaying = False
    else:
        if (i == 1):
            mixer.music.unpause()
            isplaying = True
        else:
            try:
                song = queue.get(ACTIVE)
                song = f'{song}.mp3'
                mixer.music.load(song)
                mixer.music.play(loops=0)
                isplaying = True
            except:
                messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Se ha producido un error! Puede que no hayas importado canciones a la lista. Si no es asi... Asegurate de dejar seleccionada una cancion en la lista de canciones para que se reproduzca la cancion!")

def download():
    global openMusic, entry
    i = 0
    try:
        url = entry.get();
        if (url == ""):
            messagebox.showinfo("Informacion faltante", "Introduce un URL en la entrada de texto de la derecha")
            i = 1
        else:    
            youtube = pytube.YouTube(url);
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "El URL no es valido")
        i = 1
    if (i == 0):
        try:
            directory = fd.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Seleccione destinatario a guardar cancion (SE RECOMIENDA EN CARPETA)")
            print(directory)
            video = youtube.streams.get_audio_only();
            messagebox.showinfo("Descarga lista", "Su descarga esta lista, recuerde que su conexion debe ser estable")
            video.download(directory);
            messagebox.showinfo("Descarga exitosa", "Su cancion se ha descargado, importela para poder reproducirla")
            entry.insert(END, "");
            openMusic = video
        except:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Ha ocurrido un error al descargar, probablemente tu link no es valido. Prueba otra vez, revisa tu coneccion o intentalo mas tarde.")
    else:
        pass

def move(e):
    window.geometry(f'+{e.x_root}+{e.y_root}')

p = 1

def nextsong():
    try:
        prox = queue.curselection()
        prox = prox[0]+1
        song = queue.get(prox)
        song = f'{song}.mp3'
        mixer.music.load(song)
        mixer.music.play(loops=0)
        queue.selection_clear(0, END)
        queue.activate(prox)
        last = None
        queue.selection_set(prox, last)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Asegurate de dejar seleccionada una cancion en la lista de canciones para que se reconozca la siguiente cancion!")

def lastsong():
    try:
        prox = queue.curselection()
        prox = prox[0]-1
        song = queue.get(prox)
        song = f'{song}.mp3'
        mixer.music.load(song)
        mixer.music.play(loops=0)
        queue.selection_clear(0, END)
        queue.activate(prox)
        last = None
        queue.selection_set(prox, last)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Asegurate de dejar seleccionada una cancion en la lista de canciones para que se reconozca la cancion anterior!")

def deleteSong():
    queue.delete(ANCHOR)
    mixer.music.stop()

def clearQueue():
    queue.delete(0, END)
    mixer.music.stop()

def updateVolume(event):
    global volumen
    dir = "ecordaconfigs.json"
    data = {
        "volume" : mixer.music.get_volume()*1.0
    }
    with open(dir, 'w') as arch:
        json.dump(data, arch)
    
    y = float(int(volumen.get())*0.1)
    mixer.music.set_volume(y)

def main():
    global window, entry, queue, volumen
    global song1, song2, song3, song4, song5

    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("800x500")
    window.overrideredirect(True)

    titleBar = Frame(window, bg="#000000", relief="raised", bd=0)
    titleBar.pack(expand=0, fill=X)
    
    titleBar.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)

    titleLabel = Label(titleBar, bg="black", relief="raised", bd=0)
    titleLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=4)

    closeWindow = Label(titleBar, text="   X   ", font=("Arial Blonded", 15),bg="black", fg="red")
    closeWindow.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=4)
    closeWindow.bind("<Button-1>", exit)

    bgI = Image.open('assets/bgEcorda.png')
    window.bgI = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgI)
    bg  = Label(window, image=window.bgI,bd=0, relief=SUNKEN);bg.pack();bg.place();bg.config(width=800, height=500)

    playI = Image.open('assets/play.png')
    playI = playI.resize((80, 80))
    window.playI = ImageTk.PhotoImage(playI)

    downloadB = Button(window, text="Descargar", bg="purple", fg="white", width=10, height=2,bd=0, command=download);downloadB.pack();downloadB.place(x=530, y= 235)
    entry = Entry(window, width=35, bg="purple", fg="white", bd=20);entry.pack();entry.place(x= 270, y= 225)
    playB = Button(window, height=80, width=80,image=window.playI, bd=0, command=play);playB.pack();playB.place(x=325, y= 400)
    importB = Button(window, height=5, width=8, text="IMPORTAR",bd=0, command=importSong);importB.pack();importB.place(x=200, y=400)
    nextB   = Button(window, height=5, width=7, text="SIGUIENTE", bd=0, command=nextsong);nextB.pack();nextB.place(x=415, y=400)
    lastB   = Button(window, height=5, width=6, text="VOLVER", bd=0, command=lastsong);lastB.pack();lastB.place(x=270, y=400)
    
    volumen = ttk.Scale(window, to = 0.0, from_ = 10.0, orient='vertical',length=90)
    volumen.pack();volumen.place(x= 168, y= 396);volumen.set(10)

    queue = Listbox(window, bg="violet", fg= "black", width=60,selectbackground="black", selectforeground="white");queue.pack();queue.place(x= 216, y= 35)
    clear = Button(window, height=5, width=5, text="CLEAR", bd=0, command= clearQueue);clear.pack();clear.place(x=478, y=400)
    deleteSel = Button(window, height=5, width=7, text="ELIMINAR", bd=0, command= deleteSong);deleteSel.pack();deleteSel.place(x=525, y=400)

    window.bind("<B1-Motion>", updateVolume)

    window.mainloop()

# main()
```

EDIT 2: Por peticion de lso comentarios, dejo el codigo del menu:

```
from time import strftime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from sys import exit
import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import calculator.supcalculator
import ecorda.ecordamain

def openCalculator():
    calculator.supcalculator.start()

def openEcorda():
    ecorda.ecordamain.main()

def move(e):
    window.geometry(f'+{e.x_root}+{e.y_root}')

def pos(event):
    global x, y
    x = event.x
    y = event.y

def mover(event):
    global x, y
    deltax = event.x - x
    deltay = event.y - y
    window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() + 
        deltax, window.winfo_y() + deltay))
    window.update()

def openPrimitive():
    w = Tk()
    w.title("Ejecutar Sistema de Desarrollo")
    W.geometry("150x200")

    w.mainloop()

def updateTime():
    global timetext, timeText

    hour = strftime("%H:%M (%Z)")
    day = strftime("%A")
    nDay = strftime("%d")

    if (day == "Monday"):
        day = "Lunes"
    elif (day == "Tuesday"):
        day = "Martes"
    elif (day == "Wednesday"):
        day = "Miercoles"
    elif (day == "Thursday"):
        day = "Jueves"
    elif (day == "Friday"):
        day = "Viernes"
    elif (day == "Saturday"):
        day = "Sabado"
    elif (day == "Sunday"):
        day = "Domingo"

    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    timetext = ("Bienvenido | " + day + " " + nDay + " de "
    timeText.config(text=timetext)
    timeText.after(1, updateTime)

def start():
    global timeText, time, timetext
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    timetext = ("Bienvenido | " + str(time.strftime("%d")) 

    global window
    window = Tk()
    window.configure(bg="#000000")
    window.geometry("1100x650")
    window.overrideredirect(1)
    
    ## ICONS ##

    # SupCalculator
    btn_calculator = Image.open('assets/calculator.png')
    btn_calculator = btn_calculator.resize((125, 125))
    window.btn_calculator = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_calculat
    
    # Primitive and NEXT
    btn_primitive  = Image.open('assets/console.jpg')
    btn_primitive  = btn_primitive.resize((125, 125))
    window.btn_primitive  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_primitiv

    # Ecorda
    btn_ecorda     = Image.open('assets/music.png')
    btn_ecorda     = btn_ecorda.resize((125, 125))
    window.btn_ecorda     = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_ecorda)

    # IText
    btn_itext      = Image.open('assets/txtproccesor.jpg')
    btn_itext      = btn_itext.resize((125, 125))
    window.btn_itext      = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_itext)

    ###########

    titleBar = Frame(window, bg="#000000", relief="raised",
    titleBar.pack(expand=0, fill=X)
    
    titleBar.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)

    titleLabel = Label(titleBar, bg="black", relief="raised
    titleLabel.pack(side=LEFT, pady=4)

    closeWindow = Label(titleBar, text="   X   ", font=("Ar
    closeWindow.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=4)
    closeWindow.bind("<Button-1>", exit)

    timeText = Label(titleBar, text=timetext, bg="black", f
    timeText.pack()
    timeText.place(x=10, y=2.5)

    calculator = Button(window, image=window.btn_calculator
    calculator.pack()
    calculator.place(x=45, y=70)

    primitive = Button(window, image=window.btn_primitive, 
    primitive.pack()
    primitive.place(x=210, y=70)

    ecorda = Button(window, image=window.btn_ecorda, width=
    ecorda.pack()
    ecorda.place(x=370, y=70)

    itext = Button(window, image=window.btn_itext, width=12
    itext.pack()
    itext.place(x=530, y=70)

    updateTime()

    window.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", pos)
    window.bind("<B1-Motion>", mover)

    window.mainloop()

start()
```

EDIT 3: Peticion de los comentarios, dejo la carpeta de assets

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17mpoORmhfupGvCYNBFfVRDAiaU3WrcTV?usp=sharing

Comment: Para acceder a un directorio anterior desde un path relativo, puedes usar los ..

Comment: Como seria? No entendi

Comment: Por ejemplo "../images/image.png"

Comment: Espera, que doy una respuesta mejor

Comment: Perdona, pero me siento algo cansado ahora mismo. Son las 9 de la noche aqui. En unas 10 horas o mas te doy una respuesta (si es que nadie te dio una antes).

Comment: Sii no te preocupes aca tambien son las 9, mañana respondemela si no es molestia Gracias!!

Comment: Buen dia! Estaba escribiendote una respuesta, pero me di cuenta de un error en mi idea. No se cual es la estructura de tu programa. Me refiero a tu carpeta principal y todos sus subdirectorios y archivos. Se llega a entender? Podrías agregar eso en la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Si lo entiendo! Ahora lo agrego, agregare una especie de arbol mostrando todos los directorios. Gracias!

Comment: Hola @Skeletoos57 te agradeceríamos si añadieras también la salida íntegra del texto de error que dices que te aparece para que otras personas puedan encontrarlo mejor en el futuro. Un saludo.

Comment: @JoseRodriguez ya añadi la salida

Comment: @Skeletoos57 El problema no tiene que ver con directorios. Terminé mi respuesta y la publiqué, pero la borré por que no responde a la pregunta. Podrías agregar el código de repmain.py por favor?

Comment: Sin ver el código que tienes no te podemos ayudar bien, solo vemos que importas repmain y que llamas la función main() pero no pones nada más así que puede ser cualquier cosa, pero según el error intuyo que estas intentando cargar el modulo `pyimage5` en lugar de una imagen de verdad o que a mitad de ejecución la memoria de esa imagen se elimina y no puedes volver a cargarla...

Comment: Bueno ahora pongo el codigo (el programa se llama ecorda)

Comment: A mi me funciona perfecto con el código dado. Intenté imitar el entorno de tu programa y me funciona. Podrías agregar el código del menu completo a ver que pasa si agrego eso a mis pruebas? Por cierto, te quedó linda la interfaz grafica!

Comment: A mi tampoco me da el fallo. Lo que si me gustaría comentar es que te recomiendo no utilizar globales ni tampoco nombres de variable del tipo "y,z,x,a,i...etc". Sé más descriptivo. Importas módulos que no utilizas como `pyperclip` o `webbrowser`. Hay variables que declaras y no usas como las globales de `main()`. usar `import *` suele ser desaconsejable. Ya existe un método llamado `dir` y lo estas sobreescribiendo en `updatevolume()` y declaras un argumento "event" que no estás usando tampoco. Tampoco entiendo que todo el código esté envuelto en try/excepts.

Comment: Ya actualice con el codigo del menu :DD

Comment: Gracias! pero el código está como "cortado". Sin embargo, no parece que hagas nada mal en ese código. Lei en algunas partes que Spyder puede dar problemas como esos. Usas Spyder?

Comment: Más tarde hago pruebas. Esto es opcional, pero si subes tus imagenes de assets para no tener que descargar imagenes de prueba te lo agradecería mucho :D Perdon por tantos pedidos

Comment: Sobre lo de que "en muchos lugares dicen que el fallo tiene que ver con Spyder", mira esto:

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter.TclError%3A+image+%22pyimage%22+doesn%27t+exist&biw=1329&bih=644&sxsrf=AOaemvKh1UAOiIuuRaJ0TB4DCq-YK72Jlg%3A1637693771484&ei=SzmdYeiHHfDD5OUP8fiLyAE&ved=0ahUKEwio2f_blK_0AhXwIbkGHXH8Ahk4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5&oq=tkinter.TclError%3A+image+%22pyimage%22+doesn%27t+exist&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAgAEAcQHhATMggIABAHEB4QEzIKCAAQBxAKEB4QEzIECAAQEzIKCAAQBxAFEB4QEzIKCAAQBxAFEB4QEzIKCAAQCBAKEB4QEzoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAFCLBliLBmCUCGgBcAJ4AIABZ4gBZ5IBAzAuMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: 1) Uso VS Code 2) No hay problema por los pedidos, ustedes diganme lo que quieran para solucionar este problema, ahora subo las imagenes de assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente fui capaz de reproducir el error que mencionas!

#### Explicación

Parece que la causa es que [haces algo desaconsejado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged): crear varias instancias de Tk para crear varias ventanas.

No tengo ni idea de las razones internas por las que el fallo ocurre (aunque tengo una SUPOSICIÓN, que el creador de variables para tcl que tiene tkinter tiene un contador que es compartido por todas las instancias de Tk, pero cada imagen es creada para cada interprete en particular, por lo que el contador empieza a contar desde la cantidad de imagenes de la otra ventana).

Mi recomendación es que uses Tk para crear una sola ventana, ni una más ni una menos.

#### Solución: Toplevels

En lugar de usar Tk para crear una nueva ventana, usa un Toplevel. El Toplevel se comporta casi (por no decir igual) que la ventana raiz (la creada con Tk) y tiene una relación especial con la ventana raiz , pues si esta se cierra, la toplevel también.
Por cierto, puedes crear Toplevels de Toplevels!!!

Por lo tanto, la solución está en cambiar esta linea del primer código que nos pasaste en la función main:

```
window = Tk()
```

Por esta:

```
window = Toplevel()
```

Comment: Gracias! Soluciono mi problema, pense que lo Toplevels no solucionaban eso

Comment: Creeme, no tengo ni idea de por que los toplevels lo solucionan xD y de nada c:

Comment: Jsjsjsj no pasa nada igual xd